# How to upload local file to server via sftp

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I want to upload tar gz format file to server using varien sftp

Please give suggestion

Answer (score 8):

To upload file on server with varian sftp use try below mentioned code i have tested and it working.

Replace some.server.com with your host
Replace username with your server sftp user name
Replace password with sftp password.

```
$localfilename = 'filename.tar.gz'; /* Local filelocation if you are using windows and file is in d: then your filename should 'd:\filename.tar.gz' and if you are using linux your file and your file is in /home/yourfolder then your local file name should '/home/yourfolder/filename.tar.gz' */
$remotefilename = '/filename.tar.gz'; /* Remote filelocation example you want upload file in /home/wesite1/public_html then your remote filename should  '/home/wesite1/public_html/filename.tar.gz' */
$sftp = new Varien_Io_Sftp();
try{
    $sftp->open(
        array(
            'host'      => 'some.server.com',
            'username'  => 'username',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'timeout'   => '10'
        )
    );
    $sftp->write($remotefilename,$localfilename);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Yes, its working for me Thanks oa lot Aman....

Comment: You welcome always it would be great if you accept answer and vote it. Thanks

Comment: @user40262 if the answer is sufficient please mark as accepted

Comment: @AmanAlam it doesn't work for me.

Using $localfilename and $remotefilename of your example, in my server it creates a file named _filename.tar.gz_ ($remotefilename) containing just a string: _filename.tar.gz_ ($localfilename).
Checking Varien lib, the method **write()** in Sftp.php file, it calls the **put** method of _phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php_ library without passing the $mode parameter which as default has STRING mode: `function put($remote_file, $data, $mode = NET_SFTP_STRING)`

How can I solve without touching the core?

Comment: @WaPoNe have you checked sftp php sftp is enabled on your server please check it

Comment: Yes, of course.. @AmanAlam the SFTP methods work fine but the problem is the MODE set.
Calling `$sftp->write($remotefilename,$localfilename);` as in your example, the method **write** just calls the method **put** of _phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php_ as I wrote without _$mode_ parameter; so, in this case, it interprets _$localfilename_ as a string and it copies it into _$remotefilename_.
I think you should check this.

Comment: @WaPoNe I think it's a bug. In my case `$sftp->write($remotefilename,file_get_contents($localfilename))` works fine.

Comment: Exactly @SeStro .. it's a bug.
In my case, I decided to call _phpseclib_ methods directly resolving the issue.

Comment: how to pass port, I tried port as extra key pair value in sftp open array